# IModelBinder - how do I get the default binded value for doing the change

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, model-binding

I am using model binder to manipulate some data. and I want to get the binded model from .net and manipulate it.

```
   public class FilePointerBinder : IModelBinder
    {
        public new object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
              //MyCustomSubModel  value = new MyCustomSubModel();//THIS IS NOT GOOD
              MyCustomSubModel value = (MyCustomSubModel)GetTheDefaultValueFromSomeWhere();
              value.Id = 0;
              return value;
        }
    }
```

**Edit**

```
public class User{
   public int Id{get;set;}
   public FilePointer File{get;set;}// this is null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
public class FilePointerBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public new object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("FilePointer");
        if(value != null)
        {
            //Object is not null
           return value;
        }
        else
        {
           return new FilePointer();//Filepointer with default value                
        }

    }
}
```

**EDIT:** Assuming that you have this in Global.asax.cs, Application_Start():

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(FilePointer), new FilePointerBinder());
```

You can put a break point in the BindModel() and watch the value.

Comment: Thanks, but it is coming out null. I have to mention that it is a reference to a strongly type. see my edit pls

Comment: Please see my edit. Is there any value in `if(value != null)` ?